# how to use datareader to display records in a listview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I wish to use Datareader to display records in a listview using vb.net and sqlserver
. Can anyone post links or sample code to help me? Thanks.

Comment: I think you could find the result by just googling on the net. But, Tithi's example is good one.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = Nothing
Try
    Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
    myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM DoctorRegister ", Connection)
    reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
    While reader.Read
        ListView1.Items.Add(reader.Item("FirstName")).Selected = True
    End While
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    if reader IsNot Nothing Then
         reader.Close
    End IF
End Try
```